# JOSSO session index

Tags: java, cookies, single-sign-on, josso

We have few application running on the same tomcat something like: app1.local, app2.local, app3.local...

When a user authenticates in one of them, we get cookies from JOSSO in our realization of AgentFilter, where we make some operations with JOSSO_SESSIONID.

Cookies contains only `JSESSIONID` and `JOSSO_SESSIONID`.

They are always different, then a user switches between app1, app2 and app3, but I found, that "SESSION_INDEX" on the JOSSO server is always the same for the user.

Seems like "SESSION_INDEX" is only updated for the user, until he quits or gets a timeout, and I think that SESSION_INDEX is like JOSSO_SESSIONID for our IdentityProvider, not ServiceProvider that we created for each of our instances(app1, app2, app3).

**So the question is:**

How can I pass that "SESSION_INDEX" in the cookies from JOSSO to our Agent Filter? Or maybe not in cookies?

Maybe I can use `josso_assertion_id` somehow to get the value of session_index?
I only know how to use josso_assertion_id to get JOSSO_SESSIONID.

I will be grateful for any help!!!